# My MouseWheelListener Doesn't Work

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am developing a game, but I found my `MouseWheelListener` didn't work. I had simplified my code to make the question clearer.

First, after the window is shown, click `Go In`. Then rotate your mouse-wheel, *nothing happened!* **How can I fix this?**

To show I didn't make a very stupid mistake, minimize and maximize your window or click `Do Nothing`(which do nothing at all) and rotate your mouse-wheel again, and *it prints normally!*

I am using Windows 7 SP1 & JavaSE-1.6 64-bit.

This is my simplified code which has the issue:

**ControllerPane.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ControllerPane extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String PAGE_MAIN = "MAIN";
    public static final String PAGE_LEVEL = "LEVEL";
    private CardLayout layout;
    public ControllerPane() {
        setLayout(layout = new CardLayout());
        add(new MainPane(), PAGE_MAIN);
        add(new LevelPane(), PAGE_LEVEL);
    }
    public void setPage(String page) {
        layout.show(this, page);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.add(new ControllerPane());
                f.setSize(316, 338);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainPane.java**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainPane extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public MainPane() {
        setLayout(null);
        JButton btnStartGame = new JButton("Go In");
        btnStartGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((ControllerPane) getParent())
                        .setPage(ControllerPane.PAGE_LEVEL);
            }
        });
        btnStartGame.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
        add(btnStartGame);
    }
}
```

**LevelPane.java**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
// FIXME mouseWheelMoved
public class LevelPane extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public LevelPane() {
        addMouseWheelListener(new DrawListener());
        setLayout(null);
        JButton btnRetry = new JButton("Do nothing");
        btnRetry.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
        add(btnRetry);
    }
    private class DrawListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not working on JavaSE-1.6

Comment: It does actually, just not the way you want it to, check my answer for details ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a focus issue.  The panel needs to have focus, for some reason, in order to be able to process mouse events.  You can test this with your current code by clicking the "Do Nothing" button and spinning the mouse wheel...

To fix it, you need to call `requestFocusInWindow` on the newly activated panel.  The problem is that the `CardLayout` gives you no means for accessing the current card...

It does how ever, set all the other cards as invisible, meaning if we look for the visible card, you should be able to call `requestFocusInWindow` on it...

```
public void setPage(String page) {
    layout.show(this, page);
    for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
        if (comp.isVisible()) {
            System.out.println("Activate " + comp);
            comp.requestFocusInWindow();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What events need the panel to have focus? I only know `KeyEvent` does.

Comment: Apparently so does the mouse event under Java 6, go figure ;) - Generally when I run it this kind of problem, the first thing I do is make sure that the component I want to respond to events has focus